# Distinct SUM with Mysql Count

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine

I have a query:

```
SELECT

    t1.name as Name

    count ( distinct t2.key ) as Total
    SUM ( IF( t2.time = '12:00' , 1 , 0) ) as QttMidDay 

FROM t1

LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.key = t2.key

GROUP BY t1.key
```

The question is, how i do the "Conditional Count" on the 2º parameter SUM for QttMidDay ?

Comment: OT: Since you select t1.name, GROUP BY that column instead.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - both as well formatted text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing that you can solve your problem by aggregating *before* the join.  My best guess is:

```
SELECT t1.name as Name, t2.Total, t2.QttMidDay 
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.key) as Total,
             SUM(t2.time = '12:00') as QttMidDay
      FROM t2 
      GROUP BY t2.key
     ) t2
     ON t1.key = t2.key;
```

I am not sure if the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is necessary in the subquery.